# remote desktop without monitor real display

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, anydesk

and thank you in advance for the attention.

I have an ubuntu 18.04 lts 32 bit ( don't say me to upgrade please, I cannot ). I installed on it anydesk software to remotly control it at start up also (before login).

I would like to control always the main screen with monitor on or off. If it is on I see it, if it is off I see black screen.

Do u have any solution please ?
really thank you
best regards

Comment: Welcome to AU. I’m not sure I understand your question. Are you saying you log in remotely using anydesk, and you want a black screen on the computer you’re sitting at when the host computer’s monitor is off (I can’t see why you’d want that)? Is the 18.04 system a laptop or desktop? And please edit your question to make it clearer. Thank you!

Comment: thanks, my easy question is: when i use anydesk i get black screen if the monitor is off, how can i avoid this ? thanks

Comment: the issue is that if i connect to ubuntu with anydesk, and the physical monitor is off, i get black screen ... i would like always to see the main screen ( not virtual )

Comment: the anser is "you cannot". Anydesk need a monitor that tells the system that there is something to send an image. They said they are working on a solution, but there a is a workaround. You need a dummy HDMI, like the ones they use for crypto mining. I use one for any desk and it works perfectly.